# iOS framework that dynamically links against Realm

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, realm

I am currently creating a framework for iOS and I want it to link against the Realm framework dynamically. Here are some steps I took to do this but with no success:

1. Add the Realm project into my Xcode project (I want to build Realm from source).

   [image]
2. In the Xcode target settings for my framework, add Realm (the dynamic one) as a linked framework.

   [image]
3. Add Realm as a target dependency:

   [image]
4. Import Realm into my framework's umbrella header (so that my Swift code can see it).

   ```
    #import <Realm/Realm.h>
   ```
5. Import Realm in my Swift file.

   ```
    import Realm
   ```

I suppose that now I can use the Realm framework in this Swift file but in fact my framework cannot compile. The error was:

[image]

I wonder where I have been wrong and how I can solve this problem. Thanks!

Comment: Why are you importing the header in your umbrella file if you're also importing it directly in swift?

Comment: @segiddins Gosh, I made a silly mistake. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you shouldn't need to import the header in your umbrella header if you are importing it directly in Swift.